# Simplest way to monitor 3rd party windows application for keystrokes

Tags: vbscript, wsh, arcmap

As the title says, what is the simplest way to monitor for specific keystrokes in a 3rd party windows application?

Background: Arcmap 10.2 is notorious for crashing. There is no built in autosave functionality whilst editing features so I am often losing data. While obviously the best approach is to remember to manually save my edits periodically I would like to know if I can automate this. I have been using a simple vbscript wrapper (see below) that sends the 'ctrl+alt+shift+S' keystroke (save edits keyboard shortcut) every 5 minutes. This alleviates things somewhat though the downside is that if you are mid edit when it happens you will lose your current edit.

My thinking is that I could overcome this if I could find a way to monitor for the 'F2' key (pressed after each edit), then only issue the save edits command after this is detected. I understand that this may not be possible with vbscript. I was hoping there was an 'opposite' to SendKeys though have been unable to find anything along those lines. Any suggestions?

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\ArcMap.exe""")

Do While True
  Wscript.Sleep 300000
  objShell.SendKeys "^%+S"
Loop
```

Comment: Make a shortcut to your vbs. Set F2 as shortcut key. Have your script send F2 as well. Now vbs runs when press F2, you send Fr2 and then Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S.

Comment: Your script isn't robust. If you change focus it will do random things. See `Activates an application window.

 

object.AppActivate title 
 

Arguments
object 
WshShell object.

title 
Specifies which application to activate. This can be a string containing the title of the application (as it appears in the title bar) or the application's Process ID.
`

Comment: Just in case you don't know about hotkeys. Hotkeys are also known as accelerators or shortcut keys (although there are subtle differences between them). There are two general types of hotkeys. Application hotkeys and global hotkeys. 

There are two types of global hotkeys. Application registered and window (as in what you see on the monitor) registered. When a hotkey is pressed the application that registered it is activated and sent a message that a key has been pressed. Windows when they are created can also have a hotkey assigned.

Comment: When a user sets a hotkey they are telling Explorer (the program that does the desktop, start menu, and taskbar) to register the hotkey to explorer, and explorer starts the program, and then assigns the hotkey to the window that is created. Explorer looks in only 4 places for user defined hotkeys. The per user and all user's start menu and desktop (and subfolders prior to Vista). However if it starts a program that has a hotkey assigned it will register that hotkey to the window.

Comment: Interesting idea. It doesn't really answer my question though is certainly another way of achieving my desired outcome. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately this approach stops me being able to use F2 elsewhere in windows.

Comment: You can't use VBScript to monitor keystrokes.